# Selenium WebDriver Socket Exception

Tags: c#, selenium, sockets, selenium-chromedriver

Everything was working fine till yesterday and from today onward , I have started facing the issue intermittently at any stage but frequently

> {"Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted 127.0.0.1:21235\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)\r\n   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()\r\n   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)\r\n   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)\r\n   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)\r\n   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)"}

I have already tried basic stuffs, like see if port is not in use already or bind to someone, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Not sure, what's wrong, anybody else has any idea or have faced something similar then please help me out here

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I started having the same problem out of the blue occasionally. It lasted for like, hours before I tried to restart my computer, and it went away. So, maybe one of the ancient suggestions is in order here. "Have you tried restarting your pc?"